# odom -> base_link transform not showing constant value when simulated robot is stationary

Tags: ros-humble, nav2

I have been working with ROS2 Humble as a university student, first time.

Ubuntu 22.04
ROS2 Humble
Laptop: HP Probook 450 G5

I am going through the Nav2 ["First-Time Robot Setup guide"](https://navigation.ros.org/setup_guides/index.html), however, when I try to display the transforms between the odom frame and the base_link frame, I am getting the following output:

```
At time 56.424000000
- Translation: [-0.085, -0.003, 0.145]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [-0.000, 0.000, 0.004, 1.000]
- Rotation: in RPY (radian) [0.000, 0.000, 0.008]
- Rotation: in RPY (degree) [0.000, 0.002, 0.472]
- Matrix:
  1.000 -0.008  0.000 -0.085
  0.008  1.000  0.000 -0.003
 -0.000  0.000  1.000  0.145
  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.000
At time 57.374000000
- Translation: [-0.087, -0.003, 0.146]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.004, 1.000]
- Rotation: in RPY (radian) [0.000, 0.000, 0.008]
- Rotation: in RPY (degree) [0.000, 0.002, 0.474]
- Matrix:
  1.000 -0.008  0.000 -0.087
  0.008  1.000  0.000 -0.003
 -0.000  0.000  1.000  0.146
  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.000
```

Expected output:

```
At time 8.842000000
- Translation: [0.003, -0.000, 0.127]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [-0.000, 0.092, 0.003, 0.996]
At time 9.842000000
- Translation: [0.002, -0.000, 0.127]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [-0.000, 0.092, 0.003, 0.996]
```

I have been following all the steps in the tutorial but my values seems to be off. After launching the robot description, the odom_link progressively moves away from the robot as shown on the image below:

[image]

How could I solve this issue and prevent it from occurring again in the future.